# Looping over wordpress meta to create `<TextControl>` 's?

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I'm looking for an intelligent way to iterate over available post meta, preferably by using the prefix `_postcode_pricing_`, and create new `<TextControl>` components for each. Really, I have two questions as I'm still fairly new to react and WordPress/scripts together.

**Question One:**

Does `select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute("meta")` get the whole post meta?

**Question Two:**

How would one iterate over the resulting post meta (if it gets it all) getting each, `_postcode_pricing_` option, and creating a `<TextControl>` for each?

This is my current code, hopefully, you can see where I'm trying to go with it. (This snippet doesn't work, and I don't expect it to. I'm only providing it in the hopes it helps you understand my question.)

```
const TextController = (props) => {
  // Get post meta
  const meta = useSelect((select) =>
    select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute("meta")
  );

  const { editPost } = useDispatch("core/editor");

  // loop through the meta array creating textFields as we go.
  var metaOptions = meta;
  for ($i = 0, $size = count(metaOptions); $i < $size; ++$i) {
    panelInputs.push(
      <PanelRow>
        <TextControl
          label={__("META FIELD NAME", "postcode-pricing")}
          value={meta}
          class={"metaControl-".i} // note: using class to allow react to uniquely identify each element
          onChange={(value) =>
            editPost({ meta: { _postcode_pricing_META_FIELD_NAME: value } })
          }
        />
      </PanelRow>
    );
  }
  return <div>{panelInputs}</div>;
};
```

**My Current JSON output** - `example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/postcode_pricing_pt/POST-ID`

```json
"meta": {
  "_generate-full-width-content": "",
  "_postcode_pricing_outward_code": "",           // <-- I only want to grab the following lines
  "_postcode_pricing_postal_town": "",            // <--
  "_postcode_pricing_postal_county": "",          // <--
  "_postcode_pricing_auto_1hr": "",               // <--
  "_postcode_pricing_auto_5hr": "",               // <--
  "_postcode_pricing_auto_10hr": "",              // <--
  "_postcode_pricing_auto_weekend_evening": "",   // <--
  "_postcode_pricing_manual_1hr": "",             // <--
  "_postcode_pricing_manual_5hr": "",             // <--
  "_postcode_pricing_manual_10hr": "",            // <--
  "_postcode_pricing_manual_weekend_evening": ""  // <--
},
```

**My Meta Registration**

```php
/**
 * Registers postcode_pricing_pt meta data
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 */
public function postcode_pricing_register_meta() {

    // Meta array.
    $postcodePricingMetaFields = array(
        'outward_code',
        'postal_town',
        'postal_county',
        'auto_1hr',
        'auto_5hr',
        'auto_10hr',
        'auto_weekend_evening',
        'manual_1hr',
        'manual_5hr',
        'manual_10hr',
        'manual_weekend_evening'
    );

    // Loop over meta array and register each new value.
    // example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/postcode_pricing_pt/POST-ID
    for ($i = 0, $size = count($postcodePricingMetaFields); $i < $size; ++$i) {

        // Register additional meta fields.
        register_post_meta('postcode_pricing_pt', '_postcode_pricing_' . $postcodePricingMetaFields[$i], array(
            'show_in_rest' => true,
            'type' => 'string',
            'single' => true,
            'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field',
            'auth_callback' => function () {
                return current_user_can('edit_posts');
            }
        ));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does `select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute("meta")` get the
> whole post meta?

Only the meta registered using [`register_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_meta/) or [`register_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_meta/) with the `show_in_rest` argument set to `true`. So for example, the meta can be registered like so:

```php
register_post_meta( 'post', '_postcode_pricing_postal_town', array(
    'show_in_rest'  => true,
    'single'        => true,
    'type'          => 'string',
    // I set this because the meta is *protected*, i.e. the key starts with a _
    // (i.e. an underscore), and when the meta is protected, by default it will
    // not be editable via the REST API (even if the request was authenticated).
    'auth_callback' => function () {
        return current_user_can( 'edit_posts' );
    },
) );
```

> How would one iterate over the resulting post meta (if it gets it all)
> getting each, `_postcode_pricing_` option, and creating a
> `<TextControl>` for each?

First off, I would suggest you to use `useEntityProp` to retrieve and update the post meta — see [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/metabox/#step-2-add-meta-block) for more details.

Now here's an example of how can you correctly fill the `panelInputs` array with one or more `<TextControl>` depending on your post meta:

```js
const postType = useSelect(
    ( select ) => select( 'core/editor' ).getCurrentPostType(),
    []
);

const [ meta, setMeta ] = useEntityProp( 'postType', postType, 'meta' );

const updateMetaValue = ( key, value ) => {
    // Clone the existing meta object.
    const newMeta = { ...meta };

    // Update the specific meta only.
    newMeta[ key ] = value;

    // Then set the updated meta.
    setMeta( newMeta );
};

let panelInputs = [];
for ( let key in meta ) {
    if ( /^_postcode_pricing_/.test( key ) ) {
        panelInputs.push(
            <TextControl
                label={ key }
                value={ meta[ key ] }
                onChange={ ( value ) => updateMetaValue( key, value ) }
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Don't forget to load the `useEntityProp`, e.g. `import { useEntityProp } from '@wordpress/core-data';`.

And in the above example, the `<input>`'s label is the meta key.. but I think you're able of changing that on your own?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've been pulling my hair out trying to understand this. I'm not sure if it matters or not, but I'm not actually creating a block, just editing the  `<PluginDocumentSettingPanel>` to include additional post data.

As per the Block Editor Handbook, can `useEntityProp` be used with the `<PluginDocumentSettingPanel>` without an actual block present?

(Sorry if I'm not explaining myself well.)

Comment: Yes, just like you can use `useSelect`, you can also use `useEntityProp` from within the `render` callback of `registerPlugin()`, like the `PluginDocumentSettingPanelDemo` [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/slotfills/plugin-document-setting-panel/#example).

Comment: Ok cool, is there a reason I would get a react Invalid hook call while testing your code out? `react.min.js?ver=16.13.1:14 Uncaught Error: Minified React error #321;`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to reply earlier. I actually used `useEntityProp` "directly" in the root of the `render` callback, and it worked fine for me - e.g. `const PluginDocumentSettingPanelDemo = () => { ... const [ meta, setMeta ] = useEntityProp( 'postType', postType, 'meta' ); ... }`. So I'm not sure why did you get that error, but maybe you called `useEntityProp` in a hook like `useEffect`? See [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=321) and [this](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html).